# How can I bootstrap my dependency injector services in Phalcon unit tests?

Tags: php, unit-testing, phpunit, phalcon

I went through the Phalcon docs and got PHPUnit set up and working. However, I'm having trouble bootstrapping my existing services into the unit testing framework.

Currently, I load my config, routes, and services in the `/public/index.php`. For example, I'm loading the session library:

```
$di->set(
    'session',
    function () use ( $config ) {
        $session = new Phalcon\Session\Adapter\Redis(
            ... config ...
        );
    });
```

So now, in my application I'd have code that calls `$this->session->get( 'user_id' )` to use the session library. I have many of these services -- one for SQL, MongoDB, cookies, etc.

The problem I'm having is correctly loading these services into the unit testing class. The Phalcon docs recommend loading my DI services in the UnitTestCase class ([explained here](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/unit-testing.html#sample-unit-test)) but I really do not want re-define the same services in this class loader. Additionally, I want to use the components in my application in the same ways; those components rely on the services being lazy-loaded.

So, to attempt this, I include the same `/app/config/services.php` file in my unit testing `TestHelper.php` init script thinking that I can just use the same $di object. This works in that my test cases can call `$this->di->getSession()->get( 'var' )` but as soon as a component in my app tries to call `$this->session->get( 'var' )` it throws an error:

```
1) Libraries\SessionTest::testGetSet
Undefined property: Libraries\SessionTest::$session

/home/mike/PhalconProject/app/library/Session.php:25
/home/mike/PhalconProject/tests/libraries/SessionTest.php:13
```

This error is telling me that my application session-management library `Session.php` is failing when accessing `$this->session->` via the dependency injector.

Is there something I'm fundamentally doing wrong here? Do I need to redefine the services in my unit testing class? And if I do need to redefine them, will my application be able to load its services?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the solution here seems to be structuring the application libraries to statically access the DI services.

The first step was to set the default DI in `/public/index.php` and `/tests/bootstrap.php`:

```
\Phalcon\DI::setDefault( $di );
```

Now, in the application libraries (like `/app/Library/Auth.php` or `/app/Library/Session.php`) the services are accessed statically ([more info here in the Phalcon docs](http://docs.phalconphp.com/en/latest/reference/di.html#accessing-the-di-in-a-static-way)):

```
$session = \Phalcon\DI::getDefault()->getSession();
$session->get( 'user_id' )
...
```

To make this easier, I set up a base library that all of my application libraries extend. The base library has a method to simplify this call.

```
namespace Base;

use \Phalcon\DI as DI;

class Library extends \Phalcon\Mvc\User\Component
{
    public function getService( $service )
    {
        $func = "get". ucfirst( $service );
        return DI::getDefault()->$func();
    }
}
```

Finally, `/app/Library/Session.php` would extend this `\Base\Library` class, and whenever I need the session service in a method I can just call:

```
$session = self::getService( 'session' );
```

Answer (score 0):

I have injected all my Phalcon services (which i usually get by calling DI object) using the simple PHPUnit bootstrap.php file (take a look at `--bootstrap` option of PHPUnit) my bootstrap.php contents is:

```
<?php

require_once(__DIR__ . '/../app/config/local_config.php');
$config = include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/config.php";
/**
 * Read auto-loader
 */
include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/loader.php";

/**
 * Read services
 */
include __DIR__ . "/../app/config/services.php";
```

Thus, in my PHPUnit tests i just call `$di->get('MyService');`